Jupyter Notebook (.ipynb) Not Opening as Notebook in VSCode After Merge Conflict
I'm using VSCode for my Jupyter notebook development, and I encountered an issue after attempting to git stash apply that resulted in merge conflicts. The conflicted .ipynb files now open as JSON instead of the usual notebook interface.
Here's the sequence of events:
I stashed my local changes using git stash.
I pulled the latest changes from the remote repository.
I applied the stash using git stash apply, which resulted in merge conflicts.
Now, when I try to open any of these conflicted .ipynb files in VSCode, they open as raw JSON, making it difficult to resolve the conflicts.
How can I resolve the merge conflicts and get the notebooks to open correctly in the Jupyter notebook interface within VSCode?
Additional Details:
I have the Jupyter extension installed in VSCode.
The JSON content of the conflicted notebooks includes the usual merge conflict markers (e.g., <<<<<<<, =======, >>>>>>>).
Any advice or guidance on how to resolve this issue and properly open the notebooks in VSCode would be greatly appreciated.
